Problems with Self-Signed Certificates After Server Migration Using Transwiz on Windows
Problem Description
I am facing an issue when migrating from an old server to a new one within a domain. Users have self-signed certificates configured with maximum security and a password. After completing the migration using the Transwiz application, the certificate does not appear in the signing application, and we cannot sign documents. The only available option is to manually enter the certificate each time we want to sign.
Even after deleting the old certificate and reinstalling it, it still does not appear in the application. The certificate only works correctly if installed without the Windows security level (no password). If a password is set, the application does not detect the certificate.
Additional Information
Migration tool used: Transwiz
Operating system: Windows
